Does uniform convergence on compact subsets of a certain set imply pointwise convergence in all of the set?
Suppose that

($f_n$) is a sequence of continuous functions from [0, +$\infty$) to $\mathbb{R};$ (1)
($f_n$) converges uniformly to a continuous function ($f_\infty$) on all compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ (2).

Is it true that $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to $f_\infty$ in $\mathbb{R}$?

My idea:
We want to show that, for every $\epsilon > 0$ and for all $x \in [0, +\infty)$, there exists $\nu \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq \nu$ implies $|f_n(x) - f_{\infty}(x)| < \epsilon$. So, let us fix $\epsilon$ and $x$ and let us consider the set $[0, x+1]$. Then by (2), there exists $\nu_1$ s.t. for all $y \in [0, x+1]$ (or, for that matter, any set of the form [0, a] with a > x) and $n \geq \nu_1$, $|f_n(y) - f_{\infty}(y)|<\epsilon$ and in particular this must hold for $x$, so set $\nu = \nu_1$ and we are done.

I'd say the answer is yes based on the approach below. Something about this just doesn't seem right though. In particular the fact that the functions are continuous is never used in this proof, which leads to one of my questions.
In case it is right, could the hypotheses be weakened in any way? (specifically continuity: I wanted to use this as a lemma to another exercise, so I just copied the hypotheses from there. That is also why the domain of said functions is $[0, +\infty)$.
Further, this should also prove that if $g(x)$ is a function such that $|f_n(x)| \leq g(x)$ for all $n$ and $x$, then $|f_{\infty}(x)| \leq g(x)$, right?
In case it is wrong, are there any nice counterexamples to look at? And, naturally, where does my proof fail precisely?
Thank you!

Yes, it's correct, and no, you don't need continuity. More simply put, if $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on every compact set then in particular it converges uniformly on every set ${x}$, so it converges simply on ${x}$. This holds for all $x$, so $(f_n)$ converges simply on $ℝ$.
